# Get a list of all requirements from Composer

Tags: composer-php, requirements

We use composer to install 3rd party libraries. Dependencies can have their own requirements (other libraries, but also enabled extensions). When we use Composer to install dependencies on the server, it displays errors that particular extensions are not enabled.

Is it possible to get list of requirements in advance? Like a list of extensions that need to be enabled for the given project.

Answer (score 3):

As you said: Dependencies can have their own requirements (other libraries, but also enabled extensions).

A list of extensions as you requested would depend on the list of packages you required in your project. This is why there is no such list, but the composer installer will warn you about incompatibilities.

Maybe the [clue/graph-composer](https://github.com/clue/graph-composer) package is what you are searching for. It shows all dependencies from your project's `composer.json`

Comment: Of course I want a list of extensions depending on some project :) But the graph-composer seems to be useful. Although I prefer textual list. Thanks for the tip.